# JavaScript Windows Live SDK Fails on Web Client

Tags: onedrive

This question was raised a couple of years ago, and still hasn't been answered:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/onedrive/en-US/94aef2bb-1e08-46cb-b70f-29e8d7b4c5b5/getting-windows-is-undefined-on-calling-wlinit

The Windows Live JavaScript SDK has a dependency on the WebAuthenticationBroker - which is undefined on non-Windows8 App Store apps.

`Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.getCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().absoluteUri`

Is there a different version of `wl.js` that should be used for web development?

Comment: Are you referencing the SDK like this for a web app: <script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>

Comment: Is that source documented anywhere?

Comment: This is your best bet for a reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243643.aspx - and functions that only apply to Windows app or Web apps are identified. You can also reference the debug version of the Javascript SDK which is not minified: .../wl.debug.js

Comment: Thanks, but I mean is that CDN URL documented anywhere?